# javascript filter of array with titles

Tags: javascript

I have the following code (using Chrome)

```
<script>
var arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "fn": "bill",
    "ln": "blogs"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "fn": "jim",
    "ln": "jones"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "fn": "bill",
    "ln": "smith"
}];
var lookFor = "bill";
var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return if (item.ln == lookFor) return true;
});
alert(result.length);
alert(result[0]["id"] + result[0]["fn"] + result[0]["ln"]);
</script>
```

I am trying to filter the array and return those that the first name (fn) is bill. Returning id, fn, and ln in a messagebox.

I am probably missing some knowledge of the syntax of this.

Comment: Why do you have more than one `return` in the same line?

Comment: The correct syntax would be just `return item.ln === lookFor`. There's _never_ need for `if(something) return true else return false` - it's always replacable with simple `return !!something` (or just `return something`, if that expression always results in Boolean; comparison operations do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.fn === lookFor;
});
```

> ....return those that the first name (fn) is bill

But in your code you use `item.ln`. Also why do you use two return statement

```
return if (item.ln == lookFor) return true;
```

You need just return `true` or `false` and you can do it like this

```
  return item.fn === lookFor;
```

if `item.fn` equals `lookFor` it will be true, otherwise false

[Example](http://jsbin.com/cadize/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: Yes I meant it to be fn. Thanks the === and getting rid of the "if" worked

Answer (score 0):

You should be using

```
var arr = [{
    "id": 1,
    "fn": "bill",
    "ln": "blogs"
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "fn": "jim",
    "ln": "jones"
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "fn": "bill",
    "ln": "smith"
}];
var lookFor = "bill";
var result = arr.filter(function(item) {
      return item.ln === lookFor;
});
alert(result.length);
alert(result[0]["id"] + result[0]["fn"] + result[0]["ln"]);
```

But I guess its not `ln` which you want, instead you want `fn` cause their is no `ln` which is equal to `bill`.